# Docker EXPOSE a port only to Host

Tags: docker

Is docker capable of exposing a port only to the host and not to the outside.

I need to put a docker running with a mongo database, and I wanted that it was only accessible from the host, but I need to link the host port 27017.

Is this possible, or do the only possible way is to change firewall definitions?

Answer (score 230, accepted):

Sure, just bind it to `localhost`, like this:

> docker run -p 127.0.0.1:27017:27017

Also: Your host can also talk to each container normally over its IP. Use `docker inspect $ID` to get a json dump (beside other stuff) containing the network IP.

Comment: So is it something like [1] docker run -p 27017:27017 -v /var/lib/mongodb/master:/data mongo:storage_test /usr/bin/start-mongo               [2] docker run -p 127.0.0.1:27017:27017 ...?

Comment: The second option binds to localhost, yes. The first one makes the port publicly available. If you don't want a static port, use `127.0.0.1::27017`.

Comment: This solution does **not** appear to work for swarm mode see [this github issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32299)

Comment: is the equivalent docker-compose simply `service-name: { ... ports: [ "127.0.0.1:27017:27017" ] }`?

Comment: What is the problem in my docker-compose though bind to localhost only but It is publicly accessible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50621936/docker-service-exposed-publicly-though-made-to-expose-ports-to-localhost-only

Comment: Is there different way to do this if we are running the service in docker stack

Comment: Why does it not work to connect to the SSHD that runs in the container If from outside the container in the Host I do `ssh user@containerip`? I want to use port 22. It says "connection refused". If I use `-p 22:22` that fails because it will bind the listening socket on all interfaces, whereas I want it to listen only on the interface of that docker container (`vethac516f6`)