# Docker service exposed publicly though made to expose ports to localhost only

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have created one service and exposed it to run only on localhost in one of my docker swarm node but I can access the service publicly too easily.

I have deleted and redeployed the docker stack but still same issue.

***Here is my docker-compose.yml I have used to deploy the service in stack***

```
version: "3"
networks:
    api-net:
        ipam:
            config:
                - subnet: 10.0.10.0/24

services:
    health-api:
        image: myprivateregistry:5000/healthapi:qa
        ports:
            - "127.0.0.1:9010:9010"
        networks:
            - api-net
        depends_on:
            - config-server
        deploy:
            mode: replicated
            replicas: 1
            placement:
                constraints:
                    - node.role == manager
```

I haven't added the service on which it depends as I don't think that is the problem.

> Few says its not supported in docker swarm mode. Than what is solution in that case.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue with Swarm mode.

Comment: edit: @gesellix's answer is correct, for some reason initially it seemed to be only bound to localhost, but it actually is available on all host interfaces unfortunately.

Comment: @Dmitri it is not supported in swarm mode.

Comment: similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43653699/docker-swarm-and-private-ip

Answer (score 12):

Quoting https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32299#issuecomment-290978794:

> On swarm mode, if you publish something (ports for stack deploy), it is published on the ingress network, and thus it is public. There is a few ways to get around, but putting kind/bug on that because we should at least warn people about that when doing a stack deploy with ports that have this notation (i.e. host:port:port).
>
> To work around this, there is a few ways:
>
> - first, you should publish `mongo` ports only if you want it to be *public*, otherwise, it is available through the name discovery bundle in docker (another container/service on the same network will be able to reach it through `mongo` dns name).
> - If you want to publish it in the host and not in `ingress` (so not swarm public, just on the host it is running, same way as without swarm mode), you need to use *ports expanded syntax*.
>
> ```
> ports:
>   - mode: host
>     target: 80
>     published: 9005
> ```

So, the reason is Swarm's ingress network, which makes every port publicly available. The workaround using the extended syntax *doesn't bind to the loopback interface*, but to the host's `0.0.0.0` interface, which is still an improvement compared to an externally exposed port via the ingress network.